# FragmentTabHost add a persistent Button to a scrollable TabWidget

Tags: android

I want to add a Button at the right end of my TabWidget.
The TabWidget is inside a HorizontalScrollView (added in code) 
but the Button shall not scroll together with the tabs,
but stay persistently right of the tab bar.

I'm not sure if I can customize the TabWidget that way, so another idea would be 
to place such a Button just *besides* the TabWidget.

I tried this with the follwing Layout, but the TextView does not appear.
So the question for me is, is it generally doable, or do I need a different approach ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_tabhost"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEARCH HERE"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: I solved this issue by throwing away the FragmentTabHost and writing my own tabs (which is quite easier to customize).
Please contact me if you want to have details.
I also will push this some day to my github repo.

Comment: im in the same boat, can you share your code please?